# Zoom two UIScrollViews synchronously.

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, zooming

I have two UIScrollViews. Both the scroll views contain an image. Now, I want to zoom second scroll view programmatically if I zoom in the first scroll view manually. I am using -(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView method to manually zoom the first scroll view. The second scroll view should be zoomed to the same point and scale. How can I achieve this?

Comment: provide some code which you do for your help.

Comment: Don't take 2 scrollViews.
Take one scrollview and one image view.
Pass the zoom scale factor from ScrollView to UIImageView.
(It will be better if you put some code here.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try something like this in the UIScrollViewDelegate method:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView){
    otherScrollView.contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
    otherScrollView.zoomScale = scrollView.zoomScale
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Working great!

Comment: Great to hear. 
Can you please mark my answer as the solution :)

Comment: I don't think this is correct solution... contentOffset is a CGPoint while zoomScale is a float.

Answer (score 0):

By using the tag or object of those two scrollviews you can identify the which scroll view you need zoom in viewForZoomingInScrollView method.

e.g

```
//need to set the tag for scrollviews
-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
if(scrollView.tag == 1) 
{
  return firstImageView;
}
 return secondImageView;

}

OR

//need to create the object of used scrollviews
-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
if(scrollView == objScrollViewFirst) 

{
  return firstImageView;
}
 return secondImageView;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
CGRect zoomRect;
zoomRect.size.height = manualScrollView.frame.size.height / manualScrollView.zoomScale;
zoomRect.size.width  = manualScrollView.frame.size.width  / manualScrollView.zoomScale;
zoomRect.origin.x = manualScrollView.center.x - (zoomRect.size.width  / 2.0);
zoomRect.origin.y = manualScrollView.center.y - (zoomRect.size.height / 2.0);

[autoScrollView zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
[autoScrollView setZoomScale:manualScrollView.zoomScale animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working. But as @David Williames answered, both the scroll views are also scrolling simultaneously.